# TSQL Query Help Pt. III (Last)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 queries I got from the help from this site and they are:

```
SELECT gr.g_name, (DATEDIFF(d, r.res_checkout_date, r.res_checkin_date) * pp.rate ) + ISNULL(i.inv_amount, 0)
FROM guest_reservation gr LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice i ON gr.confirm_no = i.confirm_no
JOIN reservation r ON gr.confirm_no = r.confirm_no
JOIN price_plan pp ON r.price_plan = pp.price_plan;

SELECT g.g_name, DATEDIFF(d, r.res_checkin_date, r.res_checkout_date)*p.rate+coalesce(i.inv_amount, 0) as Amount
FROM reservation as r  INNER JOIN priceplan as p
ON r.price_plan = p.price_plan
INNER JOIN guest_reservation as g
ON r.confirm_no = g.confirm_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice as i
ON r.confirm_no = i.confirm_no;
```

All the tables have the following data associated with them:

The `guest reservation` table has the following columns with data:

```
(confirm_no, agent_id, g_name, g_phone)
```

The `reservation` table has the following columns with data:

```
(confirm_no, credit_card_no, res_checkin_date, res_checkout_date, 
 default_villa_type, price_plan)
```

I need to somehow add items that a guest has ordered from the `dining_order` table (which is linked with the `r_confirm_no` from the `dining_order` table equaling the `confirm_no` from the `reservation` table), the items price must be taken from the `dining_menu` table (where `dining_order.item` equals `dining_menu.item`) and added into the above query.

The associated tables with the new information I need to add is:

The `invoice` table has the following columns with data:

```
(inv_no, inv_date, inv_amount, confirm_no).
```

The `price plan` table has the following columns with data:

```
(price_plan, rate, default_villa_type, bed_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but you could use a subquery to sum the dining items for each guest and add that to the total. This is also an outer join as the guest might not have made use of the dining facilities.

```
SELECT gr.g_name, (DATEDIFF(d, r.res_checkout_date, r.res_checkin_date) * pp.rate ) + ISNULL(i.inv_amount, 0) + ISNULL(d.total_dining, 0)
FROM guest_reservation gr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice i ON gr.confirm_no = i.confirm_no
JOIN reservation r ON gr.confirm_no = r.confirm_no
JOIN price_plan pp ON r.price_plan = pp.price_plan
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT r_confirmation_no, SUM(price) AS total_dining
                 FROM dining_order do JOIN dining_menu dm ON do.item = dm.item 
                 GROUP BY r_confirmation_no) AS d ON d.r_confirmation_no = r.confirm_no
```

Comment: When I ran the above query I was unable to fix it and got the following errors:

"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'."

Comment: There was an unnecesary semi-colon in the sql. I have updated the sql.